# How to get modified files between 2 given dates in git

Tags: git, shell, jenkins, hudson

I just want to get all the modified files in git master branch between 2 given dates and write it to a text file.

I used,

```
git diff --name-only master@{$fromdate}..master@{$todate} > /MyPath/LocationToChanges.txt
```

> In this case $fromdate is 2015-11-10 and $todate is 2015-11-13

Above command gives me a result in local PC. But when I run it through the external server its not giving any results. I have external server which is running jenkins. Here it update project and running this above given command to get the modified files between given 2 dates. If I run it manually also it is not giving any results. But if I run below line it gives me a result.

```
git diff --name-only master@{2015-11-10} > MyPath/LocationToChanges.txt
```

it writes list of files in given location. I have tested both dates separately. For both dates it gives some file names and why it is not giving any results for

```
master@{$fromdate}..master@{$todate}
```

Please explain..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't git diff work between two dates?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33781753/why-doesnt-git-diff-work-between-two-dates)

Answer (score 1):

Your Jenkins might be configured to work without local branches if it does not need to commit anything. So there might not be a local branch `master` available, so no matches can be found within the search scope. You should probably check for changes in a common remote, such as the default `origin/master` instead of local branch history. That should give identical results for all clients with matching remote configuration.

Git doesn't make any assumptions that local reference `master` matches `some_remote/master` if no tracking between local and remote branch has been set up.