# Why doesn't git diff work between two dates?

Tags: eclipse, git

I checked out a project from an internal GitLab server using Eclipse, then I pulled all the changes. When I view the history from Eclipse. (Team > show in history), it displays the full history of the project. 
Now I go to the relevant project from the terminal.

> /home/workspace/ProjectX/

I am trying to get the differences between 2 dates with the following command:

```
git diff --name-only master@{2015-10-10}..master@{2015-11-10} > /home/results/ProjectX/Changes.txt
```

It wont display any result for that. It displays:

> warning: Log for 'master' only goes back to Tue, 10 Nov 2015.

How can I get all the differences in that date range?

In addition to that, how does Eclipse request its history from the remote server. If we can run the same command from the terminal, that should work.

Comment: You can see logs older than that date in eclipse for that repo? Can you get eclipse to show you the command it is running? I expect it is probably running the log against `origin/master` or some-such and used a shallow clone when it originally cloned the repository.

Comment: Yes. It displays full history of the project

Answer (score 4):

Git parses dates like `master@{2015-10-10}` using your reflog, which doesn't appear to go back as far as you're searching. But, you can find commits for that date range anyway with `rev-list`:

```
git rev-list --since='2015-10-10' --until='2015-11-10' master
```

You want the files changes between the most recent and the oldest commit in that list, which we can get using `head` and `tail`. I'd like to use `-n1` and `--reverse`, but `--reverse` applies *after* `-n`, so we can't.

```
first=$(git rev-list --since='2015-10-10' --until='2015-11-10' master | tail -1)
last=$(git rev-list --since='2015-10-10' --until='2015-11-10' master | head -1)
git diff --name-only $first..$last
```

Setting variables and duplicating the `rev-list` feels clumsy, but the pipe-y version I can come up with is sort of worse. It picks the first and last commits, converts the newline to a space using `tr`, replaces the new space with `..` using `sed`, then passes the pair off to `git diff`.

```
git rev-list --since='2015-10-10' --until='2015-11-10' master | \
(head -n1 && tail -n1)                                        | \
tr '\n' ' '                                                   | \
sed 's/ /../'                                                 | \
xargs git diff --name-only
```

Comment: Tnx, It worked. But there was a problem which I can't understand. I went relevant project folder (/ProjectX/) and  gave the command. It gave me a result. But all those changes are not in the same project. Same workspace I have another project. Result is giving me that project changed files. It does not contain any projectX files. But there are few changes as well.

Comment: Tnx it worked. It was something else. Tnx for the solution.